# Is the given initialization of an associative array wrong?

Tags: java

Suppose I define the following statement, will an array of dictionaries (key-value pairs) be created, with all keys initialized to `"stringvalue1"` and values to `stringvalue2`?

```
String exampledatastruct[] = { "stringvalue1", stringvlaue2 };
```

Is the above statement a bad way of using?

Comment: That's a normal array, it's not an associative array. Java has `Map` object, which do what you want, but there's no simple, direct literal syntax for those.

Answer (score 9):

The above Collection type is unsuitable for keyed access. Use a `Map`:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("stringvalue1", stringvlaue2);
```

Comment: Note that the syntax is not invalid itself, but it doesn't do what the OP wants.

Comment: Well yes, rather the Collection type as it doesn't allow for keyed access to its values, have clarified

Answer (score 0):

That would simply give you an array with two String elements in it. The first would be the string "stringvalue1", the second would be whatever String the variable `stringvalue2` references. There'd be no relation between the two, other than the fact they're in the same array.

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is an array, not a dictionary. A usual representation of java dictionary is **java.util.Map**. For example:

```
Map<String, String> dictionary= new HashMap<String, String>();
```

you would put values in the dictionary in this way:

```
dictionary.put("key", "value");
```

and would get values from the dictionary in this way:

```
String value= dictionary.get("key");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a String array, not an associative array.  You should use the java `Map` interface.  Also, you can only have 1 key "stringvalue1".